# can anyone simplify this equation? $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left[\frac{n !}{j !(n-j) !}(-A)^{n-j}(-B)^{j}\right]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, taylor-expansion

Can anyone help me simplify the following equation? Any ideas appreicate. Thanks a lot!

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left[\frac{n !}{j !(n-j) !}(-A)^{n-j}(-B)^{j}\right]$

with two variables A and B which are larger than 0.

This is what I did:

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left[\frac{n!}{j !(n-j) !}(-A)^{n-j}(-B)^{j}\right]$
=$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left[n!(-A)^{n}\right] \times \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left[\frac{1}{j!(n-j)!}(B/A)^{j}\right]$

Then what I should do next? Can I use any Taylor series to replace the first or second item?

Comment: What have you tried? Showing your efforts helps other people help you (and makes them more willing to help you).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: You should be able to evaluate the inner sum directly using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: @GregMartin Because j starts from 1 not 0. Can I still use the binomial theorem?

Comment: @Jerry : $\underbrace{-f(0) + f(0)}_{=0} + \sum_{i=1}^n f(i) = -f(0) + \sum_{i=0}^n f(i)$.  You can always "fancy form of zero" missing terms. ... or split extra terms out of a series.

Comment: Thanks. Then I know what I should do.